# Missing relations in new stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-models.jar

Tags: stanford-nlp

I used **stanford-parser-2.0.4-models.jar** earlier in my application . Now I want to port my application to **stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-models.jar**. I used **edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalRelations.PURPOSE_CLAUSE_MODIFIER** and **edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalRelations.COMPLEMENTIZER** in my application to identify **purpose clause modifier** and **complementizer** relations from semantic graph edges but unfortunately I could not see them in latest version of stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-models.jar. Could some one suggest how can I do it using new jar and explain me what could be the reason behind this avoiding these relations in new jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the those details in stanford-corenlp-3.2.0-sources.jar. As part of this they removed these relations and treated them as special cases with the existing relations.
find the below comments I could see from source code

```
The "purpose clause modifier" grammatical relation has been discontinued
It is now just seen as a special case of an advcl.  A purpose clause
modifier of a VP is a clause headed by "(in order) to" specifying a
purpose.  Note: at present we only recognize ones that have
"in order to" or are fronted.  Otherwise we can't use our surface representations to
distinguish these from xcomp's. We can also recognize "to" clauses
introduced by "be VBN".
<p/>
Example: <br/>
"He talked to the president in order to secure the account" &rarr;
<code>purpcl</code>(talked, secure)


The "complementizer" grammatical relation is a discontinued grammatical relation. A
A complementizer of a clausal complement was the word introducing it.
It only matched "that" or "whether". We've now merged this in with "mark" which plays a        similar
role with other clausal modifiers.
<p/>
<p/>
Example: <br/>
"He says that you like to swim" &rarr;
<code>complm</code>(like, that)
```